# Powershell rename all files in a directory with rename value coming from the file being renamed

Tags: powershell

Ok all here is my challenge.  I have files in a directory that need to be renamed based on values in the first line of the file itself.  Here is what i have so far:

```
$dir="c:\files"
$files=Get-ChildItem $dir|Where-Object {$_.name -like "a*.bc"} \\returns list of the files matching my pattern
foreach ($file in $files){Get-Content $file -first 1} \\returns the first line of each file.
```

Now the challenge is taking substring(54,4) and (70,6) of those lines and assigning variables $val1 and $val2 and using these values to perform the rename:

```
Rename-Item <oldfilename> -newname <$val>+<$val2>+".pdf"
```

If i dont use a get-childitem and just pick a specific file I am able to assign that first line to a variable and then return the substrings.  However it breaksdown when i try to loop through the directory.

I feel like im real close but missing a way to assign that first line to a variable in the foreach running the rest of the routine on that file.

Hope this makes sense.

Here is the process working for a specific file

```
$firstline=Get-Content .\a123.bc -first 1
$val1=$firstline.substring(54,4)
$val2=$firstline.substring(72,4)
$newname=$val1+val2+".pdf"
Rename-Item .\a123.bc -newname $newname
```

Resulting file is what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

> $files = ((Get-ChildItem $dir).Name -like "a*.bc")
>
> foreach ($file in $files){
>
> $val1=(Get-Content $file -first 1).substring(54,4)
>
> $val2=(Get-Content $file -first 1).substring(72,4)
>
> $newname = $val1 + $val2 + ".pdf"
>
> Rename-Item $file -newname $newname }

Comment: That returns the same array of the first lines my orig code does. The issue is then taking that result and pulling those substrings out of each line and setting a $val1 and 2 var for each and renaming each file with those vars.  As im typing this im thinking it should probably we a do...while rather than a foreach no?

Comment: or do..while in the foreach rather.

Comment: Virtual high five, Ivan thanks.  just two typos you might want to fix in case someone else uses.  get rid of the - before in and $ missing after the plus $val1+val2.  ran on my dir and files matching were renamed!